# Is it normal and necessary to build polymorphic relation twice (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When creating a form for a polymorphic relation model, I do this in the view:

```
<%= form_for @biblio.comments.build, url: administration_create_comments_path, remote: true do |f| %>
```

and then in the controller:

```
@comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
```

Although this works, I'm wondering whether this is the best way to do things. After all, this code is building the @biblio.comments relation twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal `build` a variable twice.

First in the form you're `build`ing a template for your `biblio.comments`, which filled with the params from the form(what's not a persisted record).

Second, after params are arrived to the controller action, you're `build`
a record and save if to the database with `save` method.